# Call a method after BigQueryIO.Write successfully completes

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to run some code after BigQueryIO.Write transform has successfully finished? i.e something similar to [finishBundle](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn.html#finishBundle-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.DoFn.Context-) method.

I am aware of [DataflowPipelineJob.waitToFinish](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/runners/DataflowPipelineJob.html#waitToFinish-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.MonitoringUtil.JobMessagesHandler-) but that requires the application that started the pipeline to be running.

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a way to execute something after a `BigQueryIO.Write` transform completes.